# Facebook AP access token extending the expiration getting error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am using following API call to generate access token -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXX&grant_type=client_credentials
```

as repose from above getting Access token as following  : -
162345123675615|GmRvEjertyuiNdlaBc9zuxPjhMA

So, i am using above Access Token with following APi to extend it expiration  : -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=xxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxx&fb_exchange_token=162345123675615|GmRvEjertyuiNdlaBc9zuxPjhMA
```

getting response from above API call : - 
{"error":{"message":"No user access token specified","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}

Can anyone help me on this. Is it possible to extend above type of access tokens generated from following API  : -
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXX&grant_type=client_credentials

so ,Is it possible to extend above type of access tokens or to extend access token they need to be of other type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The access token you are receiving from the first call is the `Application access token` not the `User access token` - you can't extend the Application access token !

Comment: Thank You for your useful reply. Can i know what will be the expiration time for Application Access Token ?   If i use that token in Access Token Debugger. then it is not giving any expiration time

Comment: application access token will only expire If you reset the application secret from the application control panel

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have one query  -I am using application access token with API - https://graph.facebook.com/PageId?access_token=xxxxx&method=GET&metadata=true&format=json  but, getting following exception  : - {"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}.  Any idea the reason behind this issue ?